# How to select 'black' cells in a 3d numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

I have an NumPy array of shape `(512, 512, 3)` (i.e. a RGB image). The array is created from a binary mask, which I read into a 3d array with Pillow:

```
data = np.array(Image.open(mask).convert('RGB'))
```

I want to change the color of the oject in the mask to a RGB color. To do so, I need to select all the cells in the array which *do not* have a value of zero in all 3 dimensions (i.e. `(0,0,0)` = **black**), because this is the background.

I tried the following - coloring the non-black cells green - without success:

```
data[data[:,:,:] > 0] = (0, 255, 0)
```

and

```
data[data[:,:,:] != (0,0,0)] = (0, 255, 0)
```

Getting the following error (in both cases):

```
ValueError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 3 input values to the 8679 output values where the mask is true
```

How do I select all the 'black' cells in a 3d numpy array?

It should not be too difficult, but I cannot figure it out and there does not seem to be a similar question on S/O yet (but please let me know if I'm wrong).

This is my desired result: converting the grey mask (left) to a RGB color mask (right).

[image: Grey mask] [image: RGB mask]

Comment: Try `np.where`. : You want to set second channel to 255 when value  is not all zero?

Comment: Yes, although not necessarily the second channel: I want to assign a RGB color (green is just an example) to all cells in the array which are not black (having a value of [0,0,0]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
replace_arr = np.array([[[100, 255, 100]]]).repeat(512, 0).repeat(512, 1)
mask = np.repeat(np.all(arr == 0, axis = -1)[:, :, np.newaxis], 3, axis = -1)
arr = np.where(mask, 0, replace_arr)
```

---

Another Approach:

Create a 2d `mask(True/False)` of size: (512, 512) which is `True`
at `(i,j)` if any any of the `arr[i, j, :]` is not equal to 0.
Use`idx = np.argwhere(mask)` to get index corresponding to `True` values in the `mask` and set those indices to your new value in `arr`.

```
mask = np.any(arr != 0, axis = -1)
idx = np.argwhere(mask)
arr[idx[:, 0], idx[:, 1], :] = [100, 255, 100]
```

Comment: This solution only works for changing one color channel, but I would like to assign a RGB value (a triple) to the values which are not black (having a value of [0,0,0]).

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I meant! I prefer the second approach. Could you maybe also add a short explanation of what you did?

Comment: @Sytze I have added the explanation.